# link rel="canonical" error?

Tags: search, indexing, meta-tags, canonical-link

**Background**

I'm currently developing a website - [simplycaravan.com](http://simplycaravan.com) - and am struggling to get Google to properly index the site. We have many (potentially hundreds) of similar but unique pages that display information about different holiday homes. The URLs for these pages all begin "http://simplycaravan.com/caravan-details/?id= " and then each page has a unique id= number to distinguish it e.g. "http://simplycaravan.com/caravan-details/?id=55". The problem is that Google is not seeing each page of these pages as unique and therefore not indexing them.

**Question**

Each of these `'id=' pages` has the below tag in the header

```
link rel="canonical" href="http://simplycaravan.com/caravan-details/?id=55" />
```

Can anyone advise if this tag should be used or is causing a conflict which leads to the problem? My understanding is that canonical tag should be used if you have multiple similar pages and you want to redirect to **one page**, this is not the case for our website as we do not want to redirect all these apparently similar pages to one page, we want them to be standalone, unique webpages in their own right.

One thing to note is we have changed the id parameter in Google search console from 'let google decide' to 'every url'.

Thanks in advance for any help offered.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO